# Farnsworth-Munsell 100-Hue Test

Tags: colors

Has anyone any idea how the color codes for the caps from the farnsworth-munsell 100-hue test are? I'm trying to make the test myself, because the real one is too expensive, and I got myself familiar with the Munsell Color System. But still, I have no idea which of the thousands of Musell Colors I need for my test. And no book, or internet-site was able to tell me that so far...

Comment: I found some of them in the book "Color Vision" from Werner Backhaus et al. The Farnsworth-Munsell 100-Hue Test is widely used, there should be more information about it... some where?

Answer (score 1):

I have seen this and hope it helps. http://www.torok.info/colorvision/dir_for_use.htm

I am also looking for a free *test* for i cannot afford one =( I am kind of scared that my eyes are not good at green.